Need help forming several Lighttpd conditional redirects for PHP router
I am trying to set up a few conditional redirects for a lighttpd installation on Ubuntu.  I would like the following:
https://www.example.com/clients/xyz
https://www.example.com/admin/xyz

To pass through normally, but something like:
https://www.example.com/abc123

To redirect to the "index.php" page at the web root, where I will inspect and act on the "abc123" portion of the URL.  I would like all redirects to retain the query parameters (if any).
I'm basically building a conditional router without having all requests hit "index.php".
Any assistance would be MUCH appreciated!
I read the documentation on the settings in "lighttpd.conf" regarding "mod_redirect" usage but I'm confused as to where to start.

It's a while since I used lighttpd, but you can match the specific ones you want using rewrite-once, then catch the rest with .* - e.g.
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.example\.com|example.com$" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( 
        "^/clients/(.*)" => "/clients/$1",
        "^/admin/(.*)" => "/admin/$1",
        "^/(.*)" => "/index.php/$1"
    )
}


    url.rewrite-once = ( 
        "^/(?:admin|clients)/" => "",  # pass through unmodified
        "" => "/index.php$0"           # catch all and send to /index.php
    )

